# Appearance html code in input value

Tags: html, input, appearance, editbox

I want to do such a thing

```
<input type="text"  value="<a href="abc.html"><img src="abc.jpg"></a>">
```

but not appearance this (

```
<a href="abc.html"><img src="abc.jpg"></a>
```

) code as text.
plz help me.

Comment: What language are you using? C#/ASP.NET? PHP? Something else?

Comment: Right, but I was asking what was in your codebehind. Most languages have an escape formatting function you can apply, to avoid the manual escaping approaches described below.

Comment: Exemple of @Quentin solution with [HTML encoding](http://htmlentities.net/) compared to Barmar in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5F37/)

Answer (score 0):

For an attribute value that is delimited by `"` characters to contain a `"` character as data, it must be represented by a character reference: `&quot;`

Answer (score -1):

You should use :

```
<input type='image' src='/path/to/img.jpg'>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/jshawl/pen/iJHpL)

Comment: That would change the page from having the value as editable text into one that has a picture of the default text as a submit button.

Answer (score -2):

Use different types of quotes for the inner quoting:

```
<input type="text"  value="<a href='abc.html'><img src='abc.jpg'></a>">
```

Comment: OK, got rid of that part of the answer.